# Selecting string containing apostroph with XPath

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

In order to generate CSS via XSLT I am using the following Expression:

```
<xsl:param name="default-font-family" select="'Times New Roman'" />
```

This produces the string `Times New Roman` instead of `'Times New Roman'` which is what I need for use in CSS. Trying to enclose the name of the font in `&apos;` or `&#x27;` did not work:

```
<xsl:param name="default-font-family" select="'&apos;Times New Roman&apos;'" />
<xsl:param name="default-font-family" select="'&#x27;Times New Roman&#x27;'" />
```

Can somebody please help my finding a proper expression for this?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Besides the rather verbose answer involving unnecessary variables and/or text nodes, you might be interested to have a look at a solution that uses just `&apos;` within the select attribute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either declare a variable containing and apostrophe use that, or enter text between opening and closing param tags.  Examples as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="apostrophe">
  <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:param name="default-font-family" select="concat($apostrophe, 'Times New Roman', $apostrophe)" />
```

Or simply:

```
<xsl:param name="default-font-family">
  <xsl:text>'Times New Roman'</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
```

Both when selected will give the result you require.

Comment: You might be interested a solution using just `&apos;` within the `select` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
 <xsl:param name="default-font-family" select='"&apos;Times New Roman&apos;"' />
```

**This simple transformation outputs the parameter so defined**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:param name="default-font-family" select='"&apos;Times New Roman&apos;"' />

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="$default-font-family"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
'Times New Roman'
```